# How to check if a string exist in a arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Player objects written like this:

```
ArrayList<Player> names = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

I want to compare a string that a user inputted to see if it's in the arraylist, if it's in the arraylist, i want to remove it from the list.

```
System.out.print("Enter name of player to remove: ");
    String name = h.next();
          for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
              Player temp = names.get(i);
                 if (temp == name){
                   names.remove(i);
                }
```

This is all that I got. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does your `Player` class look like?

Comment: First: compare `String`s with `equals()`, not `==`.  Second: a `Player` is not a `String`; you have to compare `name` with a `String`-type attribute of the `Player`, such as `temp.getName().equals(name)`.

Comment: Use `removeIf` this way `names.removeIf(e -> e.getName().equals(name))` to solve it one liner (If you want to check in field of Player class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

1. The reason why your code won't work is you are comparing the reference to a `Player` with that of `String`. What you need to do instead is compare `name` with the name of a player (i.e. `names.get(i).getName()`).
2. Also, when you compare two `String` values, you should use `String#equals` instead of comparing their references using `==`. If you want to compare the two `String` values in a case-insensitive manner, you have `String#equalsIgnoreCase` at your disposal.
3. `Scanner#next` stops scanning as soon as it encounters whitespace. It means `h.next()` will not read a name with whitespace e.g. `John Smith`. You should use `Scanner#nextLine` to avoid this situation.

**Case-1:** When you want to remove all players whose name matches with the input name

```
String name = h.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    Player temp = names.get(i);
    if (temp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
        names.remove(i);
    }
}
```

**Case-2:**

When you want to remove just the first player whose name matches with the input name

```
String name = h.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    Player temp = names.get(i);
    if (temp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
        names.remove(i);
        break;// Break the loop after removing the matching player
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `break;` statement causes the loop to break after the matching player is removed.

### Original answer:

You should compare each `Player`'s name with the input.

```
String name = h.next();
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
    Player temp = names.get(i);
    if (temp.getName().equals(name)){
        names.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work if two or more players with the same name follow and delete them.

Comment: @saka1029 It is unclear if that case will ever occur.

Comment: If you are using actual names ('John Doe'), then there is a very good chance they will occur, if the number of players is large enough (maybe 50 -200 in the US).

Comment: I tested the code out to see if that's the case, it ends up deleting the first name that matches in the array list. But just to let you know, that case wouldn't occur with what i'm doing. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @Fireassassin No problem.

Comment: @NomadMaker It has just been clarified that that scenario will never occur.

Comment: @hev1 Maybe it solves the problem of OP, still it's not clear in the question how to compare, so for the future readers I don't think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `indexOf()` to know the index of name you are looking for, then delete the specify index returned from it in the ArrayList.

see the example [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-indexof-method-example/)